# Aligning the nav bar

Tags: jqgrid

how can i add a refresh button in the nav bar of jq grid.
i tried to add it and the result is shown below. the refresh button goes down the no records  to view line.Please help me to align my refresh button.

[image: Screen Shot of my grid]

thanks,
Devan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you used both `viewrecords:true` and `recordpos:'left'` parameters of jqGrid (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager#properties)). You can fix the problem with

```
$("#pager div.ui-paging-info").css({float:"left"});
```

[image]

or

```
$("#pager_left table.ui-pg-table").insertAfter($("#pager #pager_right")[0]);
```

[image]

or something like this. All depend on how you want the grid pager looks like.

Comment: @Devan: One general question. Why you almost not use voting? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) you can find the rule: **"As you see new answers to your question, vote up the helpful ones by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer."**. I think you should know this. It is not the question of the reputation. The "accepted" answer with 0 votes is interpreted mostly as "closed" because the answer is unhelpful. It would be shown as the last by the searching engine. To be clear: For me it is better if you vote the answer and not "accept" it as "accept" and not vote.

Comment: hi actually i gave my vote .it was -1 at first when i saw it..i think some1 gave you a negative vote thats why it show 0.

Comment: @Devan: Sorry. One can't seen that. Because at the beginning (till 15 reputation points) one unable to vote, many forget about this or don't know how to use the right. I want just help other people not only in giving for every the answer. It would be nice if the people would be find more helpful information directly by searching. Best regards.